# Jackson object mapper exception

Tags: java, json, jackson, google-cloud-messaging

I wrote a CGM server. There I used Jackson object mapper.( Not sure I used correct library: jackson-all-1.9) After running following exception occurred.

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for
>   class Content and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
>   (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

It says to disable `SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

Again compile time exception came.

> SerializationFeature cannot be resolved to a variable.

How to solve this? I think i have used wrong library.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I tried to use a good looking GCM server example found at http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/

Apart from changing the keys and IDs, the only thing I had to add to make it work is the following line in front of the "**`public class...`**" line:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
```

I added this line in the **`Content.java`** and the **`POST2GCM.java`** file then it was all good to go! working fine!